# Ubuntu freezes in the Ubuntu logo (initialization) when I try to install from USB (dual boot)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows, but it isn't working. I am trying to install using a USB (I already tried with 3 USBs).  The Ubuntu logo (initialization) just freezes and my machine stops.  The computer is new, its specifications are:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GPU (6GB dedicated)
CPU:
Intel® Core™ i7 Skylake - 6700HQ 2.6 GHz, 6MB Cache (3.50 GHz com Max Turbo)
MEMORY:
32GB Memória DDR4 (2133 MHZ)
HARD DISK (HDD), SSD OU SSHD:
SSHD 1 TB com 8GB SSD
SATAE M.2:
SATAe M.2 - 480GB SATA III - 6Gb/s
TELA (LCD):
15.6" FullHD (1920 x 1080p) 16:9 LED-Backlit - (Matte)
```

I already tried to install 16.*

Comment: That's so sad... i can't use my fav os.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my GTX 950M and my skylane i5.

I solved it changing the boot options in grub (e key) and setting "nomodeset" flag for installing the SO.

Following, i install the privative drivers and the skylane firmware for my processor: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares

Hope that helps you.

Comment: how did you change to  nomedeset @totemax?

Comment: Press 'e'  key at grub and write nomodeset after splash.

Comment: Hm... this is sending me to this black screen... :(

Comment: Sorry ,  works for mi :-/

Comment: Use 16.04 or 16.10. Although still supported until 2019, 14.04 is now old and you have a brand new hardware for which the newer releases provide much better support. And yes, you may need nomodeset. Make sure you type it exactly as it should be, after or instead of "quiet splash", and be careful not to add or remove spaces between that and what comes next, if any.